# /etc/machine-info is missing

Tags: ubuntu, networking, etc

I am following a tutorial about Linux networking. Tutorial mentions about `/etc/machine-info` file but my Ubuntu system is missing this file. I just have `/etc/machine-id`. Tutorial is on CentOS.

Are there any files or commands equivalent to `/etc/machine-info` in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

From the [`/etc/machine-info` definition](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-info.html):

> `/etc/machine-info` contains metadata about the machine that is set by the user or administrator.

The file isn't created by a tool, it's created by the system administrator (if necessary). It contains information which can't be determined automatically: the system's location, chassis type, deployment environment, icon and pretty name.

If the tutorial you're following requires it, you'll need to create it yourself.